# D3 not working when loading HTML into panel

Tags: d3.js

I created a webpage with two panels; the one on the left has clickable text, the one of the right is empty. When you click on text on the left, a corresponding HTML page is loaded into the right panel. It all works smoothly, except for when the HTML file that is to be loaded includes a D3.js graph, in which case the HTML elements load and the graph does not.

Here is the code for loading the HTML file:

```
function displayDetails(details_filename) {
     $("#details_panel").load("details/" + details_filename + ".html");
}
```

Is there any reason this would load only HTML and ignore the D3 chart? I've checked that the D3.js library is properly referenced. It's very worth noting that the HTML file works just fine when loaded separately, just not when it's loaded into the panel.

I look forward to hearing what you think! Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: My first thought is if your D3 code is referencing the right ID (or other html element needed). Do you see the SVG in the code when you inspect element? Can you put your code up on JSFiddle or something similar?

Comment: But if that were the issue wouldn't the HTML file not work when loaded by itself?

When I inspect element I see that the SVG did not load. Good question

Comment: I do get this error:

"File at location /var/lib/stickshift/5133e0a750044654830002dc/app-root/data/423955/prototype/d3/d3.v3.js not found"

But why would that be referenced just fine when loading the HTML by itself, and not when using the panel?

Comment: Seems like your relative path must be wrong. Are you a directory off or something? Maybe you need to traverse to a different directory in the path? I find that is a common issue for me, I forget to traverse up a directory "../var/lib/stickshift/etc".

Comment: Hmmm I'll take another look. But then, if the path is wrong, wouldn't the HTML file not work by itself? (as in, when not loaded into the panel?)

Comment: Not really sure how you have things setup. The error message you are getting is saying that it couldn't find the d3.v3.js source file. So I assume your D3 code is trying to render, but it then can't find your d3 source to work through the rest of your code.

Comment: Are you using D3 to also generate your HTML contents? Posting your code would help see what's going on.

Comment: Progress! I added more to the path and it now accesses the D3 library just fine. New problem: the D3 chart is loaded BELOW both panels now. Any thoughts on why that might happen? Also, which code should I paste to make things easy for you to see? The full page with the panels is large, and so is the D3.

Comment: Perhaps this is part of the culprit. It's the part in the D3 code where the SVG is created. Perhaps it's appending it to the body of the HTML file with the panels, rather than the HTML file that's supposed to be loaded into the panel?

"        svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom);"

Comment: In my first comment, that is part of what I was referencing "not selecting the correct html element", I'd change it to whatever div you are putting the right panel in: `svg = d3.select("#rightDiv")...`

Comment: I posted it as an answer. If it worked, go ahead and accept it. That way others won't have to read the comments to discover the correct answer. :). Best of luck to you. I've been learning D3 for a couple weeks now. It's fun, but has a good learning curve - especially if not familiar with Javascript - like me.

Comment: Accepted! Yeah D3 is fun; I'm surprised you've only been on it for weeks and still know so much.

For those of you wondering about the issue: The original issue was addressed by revising the path. When the HTML was loaded onto another page, the starting point from which the path is read was the html file in which it would appear, not the HTML file it was loading.

Then the D3 graph appeared outside of the panel. That was an issue of the D3 coding, which appended the SVG to the body of the HTML file rather than into the panel. That was easy to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind is making sure you are selecting the correct HTML element (body, #div2, etc).

```
svg = d3.select("#rightDiv")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
   ...;
```